# How to make FactoryBoy's ImageField generate image before save() is called?

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

Subj.

Right now (Factory Boy ver. 2.4.1.) with this code:

```
class ImageFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Image

    image = factory.django.ImageField(width=1024, height=768)
```

`image` will be `None` at save time, so if the `Image` model has `save` overridden and its operates with the `image`, it will fail. And thats exactly my case.

So - how to make image generated before `save` call?

Comment: Add your workaround as an answer instead. It will make it easier for other people to find :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found a workaround:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

class ImageFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Image

    image = factory.LazyAttribute(
            lambda _: ContentFile(
                factory.django.ImageField()._make_data(
                    {'width': 1024, 'height': 768}
                ), 'example.jpg'
            )
        )
```

Comment: That seems to work, but when trying to manipulate image.file.content_type, AttributeError: 'ContentFile' object has no attribute 'content_type'
is raised

Comment: @JulienKieffer were you able to solve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: `from django.core.files.base import ContentFile` 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class