# django factory boy: How to create dummy data with imagefield

Tags: django, factory-boy

I have the following model

```
class Test(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="profile_pics", default="profile_pics/blank-avatar.png"
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

How to add random images to photo using factory boy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make FactoryBoy's ImageField generate image before save() is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806428/how-to-make-factoryboys-imagefield-generate-image-before-save-is-called)

Answer (score 3):

Example solution:

```
class TestFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Test

    photo = factory.django.ImageField(color='blue')
```

https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html#factory.django.ImageField